# c# wpf Progress bar in different window

Tags: c#, wpf, progress-bar

I am trying to figure out how to use a progress bar in my application. I have a logoff form as mainwindow. And i want a additional window for the progress bar. In my mainwindow code there is a 15 second sleep. I would like the user to see the progress in a progressbar and if the 15 seconds are finished the progressbar needs to close. I want to know if there is any way for me to put the code of the progress bar in my mainwindow code. Or maybe a way to let the progress bar interact with the 15 second wait time.

Im new to coding so explaining the code is very helpfull for me to understand the code.

thanks in advance.

my code in the progressbar window:

```
public partial class ProgressBar : Window
    {
        public ProgressBar()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Window_ContentRendered(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= 15; i++)
            {
                pbStatus.Value++;
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        }
    }
```

my progressbar.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="Sessie_Afmeld_Applicatie.ProgressBar"
         WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" ResizeMode="CanMinimize"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Sessie_Afmeld_Applicatie"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Voortgang" Height="100" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <ProgressBar Minimum="0" Maximum="150" Name="pbStatus"  Margin="25,23,37,23" Foreground="#FF13B931" ValueChanged="pbStatus_ValueChanged"   />
        <Label Content="Label" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="125,66,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: This would be useful for u=> https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/4f595d3e-a435-437a-bab1-0b16d7b3f28c/how-to-use-wpf-progressbar-?forum=wpf

Comment: Why do you have a "15 second sleep"? What are you actually doing during these 15 seconds?

Comment: @mm8 i am creating a application for users to log off their own hung citrix session. I do this by using a powershell command. because i want to check if the user is logged off i need to wait +- 15 seconds untill i get no value back from my powershell command, what means there is no remaining session of this user and the logoff is succesfull.

Comment: @Jze Thanks for the helpfull link. I got it to work partially. I will keep you up to date on my progress.

Comment: @mm8 can i ask you a question. I got the progressbar to work in a different testproject. this testproject has a button and propperly runs the progressbar.

In my mainproject my progressbar runs in a diffirent window (because its ugly in my mainwindow) . can i put the working code of my testproject into the mainwindow code? or is there some way to link the progressbar window? hope you can help me out.

Comment: Please ask a new question if you have another issue. Did you try the sample code in my answer?

Comment: @mm8 Yes, i have tried the sample but it had a error saying: The 'await' operator can only be used within a async method. dont know what this means.

Comment: @Ritse: You need to add the async keyword to the method definition. Look at my answer again...

Comment: @mm8 thanks for all the time and afford! I will post another question.

kind regards,

code newb

Answer (score 0):

You can't sleep or doing something else that blocks the UI thread if you want to be able to interact with your application during the meantime.

You should do any heavy and potentially long-running work on a background thread. In your particular example, you could use the `Task.Delay` method to wait asynchronously:

```
public partial class ProgressBar : Window
{
    public ProgressBar()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private async void Window_ContentRendered(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
        {
            pbStatus.Value++;
            await Task.Delay(1000);
        }
        Close();
    }
}
```

If you are calling service method or similar, you could use the Task Parallel Library (TPL) and start a new `Task`. This is a quite big topic though. Please refer to MSDN for more information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-parallel-library-tpl.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know that sleeping blocks the UI thread. I was indeed experiencing some issues concerning not being able to interact with my app. Going to try out the Task.Delay method.